# Having problem on mobile width issue with shopify page builder (pagefly)

Tags: html, css, width, shopify, fixed-width

I'm using shopify platform and pagefly page builder it looks good on desktop but only on mobile it is looking weird. (image is below)

I already contacted pagefly support for this and they fixed issue before but it is happening again and I don't know why.

This was their reply: "It's because you have set a fixed width for an element (image) and so its width stays even on Mobile view."

[image]

Comment: Please share the part of the CSS that displays the header. You may be able to set that to 100% to fill the entire container on desktop view and it should resize down for mobile. Or you may have to use a media query but it's hard to say without seeing your code.

Answer (score 0):

Hi as i seeing your image i found there is some static with for any particular div or section for i.e. **width:200px;** please change it to % like **width:20%;**
In short in container or any other class having width in "px" convert it to the "%" as per your layout requirement and you found your problem is resolve.